# Is there any chance to find out where this exception occured?

Tags: tomcat, exception, tomcat6

I recently stumble upon a known bug of tomcat 6.0.41 : https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56561

My stack trace look like this :

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.484 | java.util.NoSuchElementException
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.486 |     at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:834)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.490 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1330)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.497 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1207)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.506 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:840)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.510 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.514 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.520 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.526 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:859)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.533 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.538 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.541 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.546 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:859)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.553 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.557 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.559 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.563 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.565 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.568 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.571 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1781)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.574 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.577 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.580 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.584 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.587 |     at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.594 |     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.loadTagFile(JspServletWrapper.java:224)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.600 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFile(TagFileProcessor.java:629)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.606 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.access$000(TagFileProcessor.java:52)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.610 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor$TagFileLoaderVisitor.visit(TagFileProcessor.java:689)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.615 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.618 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.622 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.624 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor$TagFileLoaderVisitor.visit(TagFileProcessor.java:693)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.629 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.632 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.634 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.637 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.640 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.642 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.645 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagFileProcessor.loadTagFiles(TagFileProcessor.java:707)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.653 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.657 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.660 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.664 |     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.670 |     at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.677 |     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.685 |     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.688 |     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.691 |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.695 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.703 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.710 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.717 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.721 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.725 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.729 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.734 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.737 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.743 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.749 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.756 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.763 |     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.769 |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2014/11/04 14:52:36.775 |     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

It does not mentioned any jsp file. So is there any solutions to know where the error occurs?

Comment: What about further up in the log file? If there is nothing there and you can repeat the problem in a test environment, consider enabling a lower level of logging (e.g. `DEBUG`) and repeating.

Better yet, why not just upgrade to a version of Tomcat 6 that has this bug fixed?

Comment: There is nothing more in the bottom that is of interest so I cut it. I'll try to increase log level. For the moment we don't know if we are allowed to upgrade the version of Tomcat unfortunatelly.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I changed log level to DEBUG (FINEST in Tomcat) but it does not log anything more.

Comment: At DEBUG (FINEST) level, Jasper should tell you which file it is trying to compile.

Comment: Yeah usually it does. If I write something stupid in jstl it will tell me the line and the file but in this precise case it's different I don't know why.